# How can I obtain true matrix

Tags: python

I have Question for this matrix:

```
A=([[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]])
```

And I want obtain another matrix from A as below:

```
B=([[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Iwritten for this:

```
import numpy as np
n=np.matrix('[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2]')
c=np.matrix('[0, 0, 0, 0]')
d=np.zeros((1,4))
for i in np.nditer(n):
    h=d.itemset((0,i-1),1)
    print d
```

But I obtain wrong matris as below

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.  1.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

How can I obtained true(B) matrix????

Comment: Is the row `[0, 1, 0, 1]` right?

Comment: short answer: put `d=np.zeros((1,4))` inside the `for` loop, so the 1's don't accumulate.  But then you still aren't creating a matrix, just printing out its rows. See various answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple numpy solution, loop probably may be replaced with vectorized operation for better performance.

You had an error in your test case, seventh row should be `[0, 0, 0, 1]` instead of `[0, 1, 0, 1]`.

```
import numpy as np

n = np.matrix([2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2])
expected = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [0, 1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0, 0]])


def make_result(input_vector):
    output = np.zeros((input_vector.shape[1], np.max(input_vector)))
    for idx, value in enumerate(np.nditer(n)):
        output[idx, value - 1] = 1
    return output


result = make_result(n)
assert (expected == result).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
from pprint import pprint

A=[[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]]
B = [[0]*4 for _ in range(len(A[0]))]

for i,val1 in enumerate(B[:]):
    B[i][A[0][i]-1]=1

pprint(B)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting. Its realy helpful for me thanks again and again

Comment: However this is not a numpy matrix. So you lose all the performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

May be faster to go by columns if there are few columns and many rows.

```
import numpy as np
n=np.matrix('[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2]')
d=np.zeros((n.shape[1],4),dtype=int)
for j in range(4):
    d[:,j] = n==j+1  #  True->1, False ->0
print d

[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]
```